# How can I convert a pytorch tensor of an image of the shape (batch, channels, height, width) to (batch, height, width)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to turn a colored image into a grayscale image by removing the color channels. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Grayscale` transform

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Grayscale.html

```
from torchvision.transforms import Grayscale

grayscale_batch = Grayscale()(color_batch)
```

Which results in a (batch_size, 1, H,W) tensor.

To remove the channel dimension, apply `torch.squeeze()`

Comment: That still results in the shape (batch, channels, height, width), just with 1 channel instead of 3. I would like to remove the color channel completely.

Comment: I updated the answer, but be careful if your batch size is 1, `squeeze` will also remove this dimension, so specify `dim = 1` if this can happen